# Fixing x_range in plotly express histogram messes up x axis in rug plot

Tags: python, plotly, histogram, plotly-dash, plotly-express

I am creating a histogram using plotly express, and I want to use the argument `marginal='rug'`. When trying to disable zooming on the x axis by using `histogram.update_xaxes(fixedrange=True)`, this messes up the x range in the rugplot.

Here are the two outputs, one with `fixedrange=False` and one with `fixedrange=True`. Note how the points above the bars are off in the second plot.

[image: Histogram without fixed range]

[image: Histogram with fixed range]

I would really like to disable the zooming, but have the x axes match between the bars and the points. How do I do this?

For reproducibility, here's the code for this minimal example, you can just copy and run it.

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import dash_daq as daq


app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(id="graph"),
    html.Label("Make x axis zoomable"),
    daq.ToggleSwitch(
            id='x_toggle_switch',
            value=False
        )
])


@app.callback(
    Output("graph", "figure"),
    [Input('x_toggle_switch', 'value')])
def make_x_zoomable(x_zoomable):
    start, end = 0, 25
    df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25]})
    histogram = px.histogram(df, x='x',
                             nbins=end - start + 1,
                             range_x=[start, end],
                             marginal='rug',
                             barmode='overlay',
                             template='plotly_white')
    histogram.update_layout(showlegend=False, yaxis_title='y', xaxis_title='x')

    # disable zooming
    histogram.update_xaxes(fixedrange=x_zoomable)
    histogram.update_yaxes(fixedrange=True)

    return histogram


app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: I tried to run plotly by itself, but the situation is the same whether fixedrange is True or False. Are you using the latest version (5.3.1)?

Comment: Yes, my plotly was at 5.3.1, dash at 2.0.0 and dash-renderer at 1.9.1. I tried updating all packages (used conda), and still got the same thing. Interestingly, I also set up a venv from scratch (now without conda), and now I can't reproduce it. So there seems to be some package weirdness going on. Thank you!